# Exporting as stand alone application

Tags: java, processing

I exported Processing application as a standalone application with embedded Java, but the exe does not work in computers where Java/Processing is not installed. Even if the Windows 64 bits works with Java embedded, the 32 bits does not work with Java embedded or not. The computers that do not have Java already installed open the Windows 64 bits exe but not the Windows 32 exe (with java embedded in its exporting process). Here's the post in Processing forum: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/25373/no-export#latest 
Can it be resolved? Thanks.

Comment: I remember running into this issue on Windows a while back and I went for a very hacky workaround to installing a JRE. Processing already has a JRE, so I added that and `processing-java.exe` to Environment Variable, then used `processing-java` to run the sketch instead of exporting an application. Not sure if that applies for your setup

Comment: Thanks, will try on win 32 to see if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can only include the Java version for the type of machine you're running on.

If you're on a 64-bit Windows machine, then you can only include Java in the 64-bit Windows application. If you're on a 32-bit Linux machine, then you can only include Java in the 32-bit Linux application.

If you really want to include Java for a bunch of different machines, then your best bet is to find each type of machine and do the export from them. Find a 32-bit Windows machine and do the export there, then find a 64-bit Linux machine and do the export there, etc.

You **might** be able to hack something together by downloading the JRE for each type of machine and manually including it, but that might get pretty tricky. Note that this is **not** as simple as just copying a folder into your application directory. You're going to have to change the run script file as well.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on exporting applications from Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/exporting-applications).

Comment: All I need is 32-bit Windows and maybe 64-bit as well. I do not know much about coding/computers to make apps for linux as well. Two questions. One, can you elaborate on the JRE part you mentioned, which JRE and where to download. How to change the run script file? (What is a script file?). Second, is it easier to make an app in Java (Eclipse) and export as a Jar file? Is there a Jar to exe converter? Is there any such complication in the Jar file export? Pl let me know.

Comment: @sonia That is a lot of questions, and Google is your friend for most of them. If you don't understand what a JRE is, then you probably shouldn't be trying to hack executables together. But basically what I meant was you would need to download the JRE for each machine you want to deploy to, and then you'd modify the exported script files to use those JREs. Look at how it works in the exported applications already. You can export jars from eclipse, but I don't know that it's easier. And yes there are Jar to exe bundlers. Again, Google is your friend here.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in the Processing forum post, I'm really only a novice who has tried a hand at making a simple app, thanks to Google. However, exporting as an app to PC (esp win 32-bit) seems really tricky and that does not seem to be resolved yet. I did come across jre and changes to script etc., earlier but was not sure if one needed to go so deep for exporting. Since you'd written a tutorial on exp app, I was just wondering if you cld help with a similar step by step guide to the jre and hacking script etc., in yr response. Anyway, thanks, I'll google and try to get to the deep end :-)